# extend ECMAScript by adding new keywords and syntax

Tags: programming-languages, parsers, language-design

I would like to extend ECMAScript by adding new keywords and syntax to it, for example:

|variableName| stipulates a special kind of variable which I would like to be able to include in a normal ECMAScript line of code, for example:

```
|variable1| = 1 + 1
|variable1| = |variable2|.length - 3
```

a more complex one would be:

```
@SpecialObject[propertName:propertyValue,..., propertyNameN:propertyValueN] {
    {|variable1| == true} => {
        console.log("condition 1 applies")
        |variable1| = false
    }
    .
    .
    .
    {|variable2|.length !== 0} => {
        console.log("variable 2 contains elements")
        |variable2| = Date.now()
    }       
}
```

I have built an initial prototype by impementing my own lexer and parser (using [Chevrotain](http://sap.github.io/chevrotain/website/)), but it is quite limited as it only supports those specific constructs of my new syntax, **what I would like to do is to make it more powerful by being able to include ECMAScript code in my syntax, how could it be done?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know of two plausible approaches:

One approach is to start with a lexer and parser for ECMAScript and modify them.

Another approach is to build your own preprocessor that takes as input a program with your syntax, and transforms it to EMCAScript which can be accepted by an existing interpreter (by replacing instances of `|variable|` with something that does fall within the normal ECMAScript syntax).  Since you haven't told us anything about the semantics of the `|variable|` syntax, I can't make any suggestions for a specific transformation to apply, but you might be able to work one out.